# ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

**it keeps bringing this error ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected on this line of code
`public address owner;` here is the full code**

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract BasicToken is owned {
    uint public totalSupply;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint public decimals = 18;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed _tokenOwner, address indexed _spender, uint tokens);
    event Burn(address indexed _from, uint256 _value);
    

    constructor (string tokenName, string tokenSymbol, uint initialSupply) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply*10**uint256(decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender]= totalSupply;
        name = tokenName;
        symbol = tokenSymbol;
    }

    function _transfer(address _from,address _to,uint256 _value ) internal {
        require(_to != 0x0);
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        allowance [_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success){
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval (msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function mintToken (address _target, uint256 _mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[_target] += _mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += _mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(0, owner, _mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(owner, _target, _mintedAmount);
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        totalSupply -= _value;
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }
}


contract owned {
    public address owner;

    constructor {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership (address newOwner) onlyOwner{
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are some errors:

in `own` contract

1- Instead of `public address owner`

```
   address public  owner;
```

2- instead of `constructor`

```
  constructor()
```

3- add visibility to `transferOwnership`. I added `public`

```
 function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner{
```

4- Since you are inhering from `owner` contract place it on top. Otherwise you get "definition of base has to precede definition of derived contract" error.

in `BasicToken` contract

1- add visibility  like `public` to the last few functions

2- in `constructor` signature remove `public` (since I compiled at version 0.8.7 but in your version it was necessary I guess) and add `memory` for string args

```
constructor (string memory tokenName, string memory tokenSymbol, uint initialSupply) {
```

3-

```
  function _transfer(address _from,address _to,uint256 _value ) internal {
    // not 0x0 because _to is address type
    require(_to != 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
    // or require(_to != address(0);
```

4- in `mintToken`

```
function mintToken (address _target, uint256 _mintedAmount) public onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[_target] += _mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += _mintedAmount;
        // not 0, address(0)
        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, _mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(owner, _target, _mintedAmount);
    }
```

I compiled  it at version `pragma solidity ^0.8.7;`

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful, the code is working perfectly now